# How to hide/disable safeAreaView fake corners in some android phones?

Tags: android, react-native, safeareaview, react-native-safe-area-view

I have an app with a landscape screen using canvas and some drawing features. For some android devices the safeArea has border radius. Is there a way to disable this border radius.

Device without the border radius:

[image]

Device with the border radius:

[image]

Comment: Where are you paying for Border Radius?

Comment: Sorry I don't undestand

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your question is related to `react-native`. It is more related to how android records the screen.

But as an answer to your question No, you cannot change the color of the hidden part of the screen

Comment: Actually you can support the notch area in your app, check this:https://dev.to/brunolemos/adding-notch-support-to-your-react-native-android-app-3ci3, but the issue with this is when showing modals the notch area is not styled.

Comment: Please correct me if I misunderstood. You are recording the screen and it's ok, But the recorded video comes with a black border-radius, and this is what you want to change right?

Comment: The recording does not add any border to the video, it's already there in the layout. Sorry if i did not explain the issue very well. The images is from two different phones, the second one has the border radius.

Comment: Ok, I'm not sure if I did understand what is your issue. Please provide more information or try other words to describe the issue.